# Monitoring Samba Activity with Full_Audit

Tags: logging, samba

I have samba server. I've configured smb.conf like this:

```
[global]
# Another configuration
#
#

# Audit Activity Settings
full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%m|%S
full_audit:success = mkdir rename unlink rmdir pwrite pread
full_audit:failure = none
full_audit:facility = local7
full_audit:priority = NOTICE

[shared]
comment = Shared Content 
path = /data/shared
read only = no
browsable = yes
vfs objects = full_audit
```

I want to throw samba log to specific file, for example to `/var/log/samba/log.audit`. I've configured in rsyslog.conf like this:

```
if $syslogfacility-text == 'local7' and $programname == 'smbd' then /var/log/samba/log.audit
```

but nothing happen, no file log log.audit at `/var/log/samba/`.

And I have too try configured at `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf` like this:

```
local7.* /var/log/samba/log.audit
```

but same, no file log `log.audit` at `/var/log/samba/`.

But, Full_Audit logs available at syslog:

```
Mar 20 02:49:26 media-arsip smbd_audit: content|192.168.84.69|ubspok18|shared|mkdir|ok|sharedcontent/ok/tes
```

How to throw that syslog samba full_audit logs to `/var/log/samba/log.audit` ?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you have resolved this already, however for posterity if so:

The resolution that worked in my case when I ran into both of these issues (on a CentOS 7 samba server) was two-fold.

Firstly: when vfs full_audit was configured with the `local7` context, log entries were getting sent on to boot.log, which was already configured for that context. Defining a new context in **smb.conf** `full_audit:facility = local5` and **/etc/rsyslog.conf** `local5.* /var/log/smb_audit.log` sent audit log messages to the chosen log file (in my case, **/var/log/smb_audit.log**).

Secondly: After the above configuration, log messages were sent to *both* my defined log file and syslog. This was because the local5 needed to be disabled for syslog in **/etc/rsyslog.conf** in order for syslog to not slurp them up as well as a default behaviour. This was accomplished by adding `local5.none` to my configuration line for **/var/log/messages**, so it ends up something like: `*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local5.none   /var/log/messages`.

(`smbcontrol all reload-config && systemctl restart systemd-journald && systemctl restart rsyslog` for these updates to take effect. Journald does not need to be restarted unless you are also choosing to increase your log limit/rate window, though for a reasonably heavily trafficked server, this may be desirable.)